# How to run equal number of tests in different nodes using selenium grid?

Tags: selenium, grid

I have 1000 tests and 5 nodes are registered with hub and i want to execute 200 tests in each node. How to accomplish this?

Comment: what have you already tried? what did not work? where did you get stuck?

Answer (score -1):

`maxInstance` is used to limit the number of browser initialization in a node.

For example if you want to run 200 test cases in a node you can specify the number of instances while registering the node.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar 
   -role node 
   -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register 
   -port 5556 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstance=3
```